# SQL syntax error: оператор WITH

Tags: sql, mariadb

У меня есть запрос на mariaDB:

```
SELECT AVG(selectOnStop.time_avg)                                             AS global_avg_time,
       AVG(selectFromStopTaskProcessor.time_avg)                              AS qmr_task_time,
       AVG(selectOnStop.time_avg) - AVG(selectFromStopTaskProcessor.time_avg) AS postprocessing
FROM (SELECT
        global_task_id,
        SUM(time_from_start),
        SUM(time_from_start) / 1000000 AS time_avg
      FROM task AS t
             INNER JOIN recorderevent AS r ON (CONCAT(r.task_id, '0', SUBSTRING(r.`shard_alias` FROM 7)) = t.id)
      WHERE r.event_name = 'STOP'
      GROUP BY global_task_id
      ORDER BY SUM(time_from_start) DESC) AS selectOnStop
       JOIN (SELECT global_task_id, SUM(time_from_start) / 1000000 AS time_avg
             FROM task AS t
                    INNER JOIN recorderevent AS r ON (CONCAT(r.task_id, '0', SUBSTRING(r.`shard_alias` FROM 7)) = t.id)
             WHERE r.event_name = 'QMR_STOP_TASK_PROCESSOR'
             GROUP BY global_task_id
             ORDER BY SUM(time_from_start) DESC) AS selectFromStopTaskProcessor;
```

Запрос работает. Я решил переписать его с использованием оператора WITH.

```
WITH selectOnStop (time_start, time_avg) AS (SELECT
                                               SUM(time_from_start)           AS time_start,
                                               SUM(time_from_start) / 1000000 AS time_avg
                                             FROM task AS t
                                                    INNER JOIN recorderevent AS r
                                                               ON (CONCAT(r.task_id, '0', SUBSTRING(r.`shard_alias` FROM 7)) = t.id)
                                             WHERE r.event_name = 'STOP'
                                             GROUP BY global_task_id
                                             ORDER BY SUM(time_from_start) DESC)
    ,
     selectFromStopTaskProcessor (time_average) AS (SELECT SUM(time_from_start) / 1000000 AS time_average
                                                    FROM task AS t
                                                           INNER JOIN recorderevent AS r
                                                                      ON (CONCAT(r.task_id, '0', SUBSTRING(r.`shard_alias` FROM 7)) = t.id)
                                                    WHERE r.event_name = 'QMR_STOP_TASK_PROCESSOR'
                                                    GROUP BY global_task_id
                                                    ORDER BY SUM(time_from_start) DESC)

SELECT AVG(selectOnStop.time_avg)                                                 AS global_avg_time,
       AVG(selectFromStopTaskProcessor.time_average)                              AS qmr_task_time,
       AVG(selectOnStop.time_avg) - AVG(selectFromStopTaskProcessor.time_average) AS postprocessing
FROM selectOnStop
       JOIN selectFromStopTaskProcessor;
```

По сути, я просто перенёс селекты в отдельные запросы. Пишет следующее:

> [42000][1064] (conn=3) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'selectOnStop (time_start, time_avg) AS (SELECT
>   [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'selectOnStop (time_start, time_avg) AS (SELECT ' at line
>   1 Query is: WITH selectOnStop (time_start, time_avg) AS (SELECT
>   SUM(time_from_start) AS time_sta ...

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, и что надо поправить в запросе, чтобы он работал?

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваша СУБД (конкретной вашей версии) умеет CTE?

Comment: В mariadb CTE появились в 10.2.1 (альфа), первый стабильный релиз этой ветки был 10.2.6. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1021-release-notes/ А у вас какая версия?

Comment: У меня 10.1.37. Судя по всему, ошибка в этом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При получении синтаксической ошибки на вроде бы корректный запрос имеет смысл последовать совету из текста ошибки:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

И проверить документацию по этому синтаксису именно для своей версии СУБД.

Для `mariadb` поддержка выражения `WITH` и `common table expression` появилась не так уж давно, в альфа-версии [10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1021-release-notes/). Первый стабильный релиз был 10.2.6. У вас же версия 10.1.37 - то есть предшествующая ветка и, соответственно, `CTE` ещё не поддерживает.